# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {a_i}{1+a-a_i} + \prod_{i=1}^{n} {(1-a_i)} \leq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> Assume $0 < a_i\leq 1$ for $i = 1,2,...,n,$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}
> = a.$$ Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {a_i}{1+a-a_i} + \prod_{i=1}^{n} {(1-a_i)} \leq 1.$$

I first substituted $b_i = 1-a_i, 0 < b_i\leq 1$ to simply the problem to $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {1-b_i}{a+b_i} + \prod_{i=1}^{n} {b_i} \leq 1.$$ Rearranging: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {1-b_i}{a+b_i}  \leq 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} {b_i}.$$  From here I thought about trying to telescope the sum and but didn't really get far, and I'm not sure how to deal with the product and sum in the same inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Consider $$f\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right):=\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{a_i}{1+\sum_{j\in[n]\setminus\{i\}}\,a_j}+\prod_{i=1}^n\,\left(1-a_i\right)$$
for $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in[0,1]$.  Observe that $f$ is convex in each variable.  Therefore, the maximum value of $f$ is attained at the boundary.  The task is now to show that
$$f\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)\leq 1$$
for all $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\{0,1\}$.

Fix $\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)\in\{0,1\}^n$.  Let $Z:=\left\{i\in[n]\,|\,a_i=1\right\}$.  Ergo, if $Z$ is nonempty, then we have
$$f\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)=\sum_{i\in Z}\,\frac{1}{|Z|}=1\,.$$
If $Z=\emptyset$, then $a_i=0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, whence
$$f\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\,1=1\,.$$
In fact, $f\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\right)=1$ if and only if $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\{0,1\}$.